# Mcdonalds like couponing system

Tags: javascript, html, css, coupon

I'm busy making a site for a friend that has a restaurant. He wants to use a couponing system like the one from mcdonalds where you click on a coupon, see it for like 10 minutes and then disappers or greys out or something.

what i have been trying to do isn't working because i use a time that i set to count down to but the timer has to start the moment you click on it.

```js
function f2() {
  document.getElementById('demo1').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  //form validation that recalls the page showing with supplied inputs.    
}

function f1() {
  document.getElementById('demo1').style.backgroundColor = 'darkgreen';
  //form validation that recalls the page showing with supplied inputs.    

  // Set the date we're counting down to
  var countDownDate = new Date("Mar 11, 2020 16:51:00").getTime();

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = //days + "d " + hours + "h "
      "Nog " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s" + " geldig!";



    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("demo").src = "https://2benc.nl/noos/image1.png"
      document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://2benc.nl/noos/geometric-leaves.png')";
      document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      document.getElementById("demo1").style.display = "none";
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>restaurant</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://2benc.nl/noos/semantic/semantic/semantic.min.css">
  <script src="https://2benc.nl/noos/semantic/semantic/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://2benc.nl/noos/semantic/semantic.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="ui four column divided padded grid">
    <div class="stretched row">
      <div class="column" style="height: 200px; display:none">
        <div class="ui segment">
          <p>zalmschotel</p>
          <img class="ui image" id="demo" src="image.png">
          <p>van €15,-</p>
          <p>voor €5,-</p>

          <div class="ui segment" id="demo1" style="text-align: center;background: green;" onmousedown="f1()" onMouseUp="f2();">
            <a style="color:#fff;font-weight: bold;">Inleveren</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <div class="ui segment">
          1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="ui segment">
          1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="ui segment">
          1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

it works on: https://www.2benc.nl/noos/

so im stuck hope you can help me out here..

Comment: Can you expand on what part isn't working? The snippet clearly has funny results, but are you having trouble setting the endtime of your countdown? Or is it something about the displayed text?

Comment: What i now have is something that has a endtime set by me. So if you click on the button now the item has expired because the time and date set by me has passed. What i would like is a countdown that starts counting down the moment you click on it and then expires.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what doesn't work, because you didn't clearly state. Anyway, remove the `display: none` from `<div class="column" style="height: 200px; display:none">` (your clickable element that triggers the timer is in this div) and use a future date in the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

If your only trouble is generating an end-time at some specified time-after-click in the future, then it's an easy modification. Inside your `f1()` just modify your countdown date:

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date().getTime(); // this is now
countDownDate += 1000 * 60 * 10; // add 10 minutes
```

You can easily add various amount in ms for whatever timeframe you have in mind:

```
countDownDate += 1000 * 30; // add 30 seconds
countDownDate += 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2; // add 2 hours
countDownDate += 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3; // add 3 days
```

Of course, all this will only apply while the page stays open - refreshing or revisiting the page will start brand new timers without reference to timers started by other clients or other sessions.